# how to connect one method to diffrent objects?

Tags: javascript, object

Can you please guide me a little with the exercise i came across during learning about objects and prototypes in Javascript?

Lets just say that I have to create simple food chain with 3 animals (cat bird worm).

And it should implements 3 objects in the way that the following output will be posible(all objects should implement the same method "eat"):

```
    var cat1 = Object.create(Cat);
var cat2 = Object.create(Cat);
var bird = Object.create(Bird);
var worm = Object.create(Worm);
cat1.eat(bird); // "Tasty!"
cat2.eat(bird); // "Tasty!"
bird.eat(worm); // "Tasty!"
worm.eat(cat1); // "Bleeh!"
cat1.eat(cat2); // "Bleeh!"
```

So when I am creating objects:

```
var Cat  = {
   eat = function(){}
};
var Bird = {
   eat = function (){}
};
var Worm = {
   eat = function (){}
};
```

Where I should put "if" statements to determine when return proper values?(cat eat bird, bird eat worm, bird can't eat bird etc.) And also is there any other way to write one method eat to all animals ?

Comment: *Cat* should be an object literal, so `var Cat = {eat: function (food) {/*process food*/}};` and so on.

Answer (score 1):

One way you could go is to define an Animal "class" which is a function in JS (at least in ES5). You can then create the Cat "class" which will inherit the Animal one, and in it you define what it eats. The `eat` function will be a generic one in the Animal class, this way you don't have to override it each time with different values.

```
var Animal = function() {
    this.canEat = [];
}
Animal.prototype.eat = function (animal) { 
    if (this.canEat && this.canEat.indexOf(animal) !== -1) {
        console.log('Yum!'); 
    }
    else {
        console.log('Bleh!');
    }

};

var Cat = function() {
    this.canEat = ['bird'];
}

// Inheritance
Cat.prototype = Object.create(Animal.prototype);

var cat = new Cat();
cat.eat('bird');  // Yum!
cat.eat('cat');   // Bleh!
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/68x89ght/)

Answer (score 1):

You have to organize, objects in proper way and you have to go with inheritance.

```
var Animal = {
  // set food chain hierarchy
  // worm -> 1, birds -> 2, cat -> 3, lion -> 4
  level: 0,
  eat: function(otherAnimal) {
    return this.level > otherAnimal.level ? 'Tasty':'Bleeh';
  },
  init: function(level){
    this.level = level;
    return this;
  }
};

var cat1 = Object.create(Animal).init(3);
var cat2 = Object.create(cat1);
var bird = Object.create(Animal).init(2);
var worm = Object.create(Animal).init(1);

cat1.eat(bird); // "Tasty!"
cat2.eat(bird); // "Tasty!"
bird.eat(worm); // "Tasty!"
worm.eat(cat1); // "Bleeh!"
cat1.eat(cat2); // "Bleeh!"
```

Answer (score 0):

Working [**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/AdityaParab/qed0wkn8/16/)

```
function Organism(){};
function Cat(){};
function Bird(){};
function Worm(){};

Organism.prototype.eat = function(food){
    if(this.level > food.level){
        console.log('Tasty!');
    } else {
        console.log('Bleeh!');
    }
}

Cat.prototype = new Organism();
Cat.prototype.level = 3;

Bird.prototype = new Organism();
Bird.prototype.level = 2;

Worm.prototype = new Organism();
Worm.prototype.level = 1;

var cat1 = new Cat();
var cat2 = new Cat();
var bird = new Bird();
var worm = new Worm();

cat1.eat(bird); // "Tasty!"
cat2.eat(bird); // "Tasty!"
bird.eat(worm); // "Tasty!"
worm.eat(cat1); // "Bleeh!"
cat1.eat(cat2); // "Bleeh!"
```